# In the attention mechanism, why are there separate weight matrices for the queries and keys?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, attention

To perform [self attention](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) over a collection of $n$ vectors stacked up into a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, we first obtain query, key, and value representations of these vectors via three linear transformations:
$$
\begin{align*}
Q & = XW_Q \\
K & = XW_K \\
V & = XW_V.
\end{align*}
$$
Then for each query, we take a weighted combination of the value vectors, where the value vectors with the largest weights are the ones whose key vectors have the largest inner products with the query vector:
$$
\text{Attention}(Q, K, V ) = \text{softmax}\left(\frac{QK^\top}{\sqrt{d_k}} \right)V.
$$
So far, so good. But if we combine these two steps together into a single equation, we get
$$
\text{Self-Attention}(X) = \text{softmax}\left(\frac{XW_QW_K^\top X^\top}{\sqrt{d_k}} \right)XW_V,
$$
at which point an apparent redundancy arises: Why maintain separate weight matrices $W_Q$ and $W_K$ as opposed to just their product $W = W_Q W_K^\top$ (which would reduce the trainable parameter count by at least half)?

Besides the fact that this would make the query-key-value analogy a little fuzzier, my only guess about the motivation of this choice is that the authors also mention using additive attention instead of the multiplicative attention above, in which case I believe you would need two separate weight matrices.

Comment: I asked the same question, and the answer is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515477/when-calculating-self-attention-for-transformer-ml-architectures-why-do-we-need):

Comment: @itrase this is helpful, thanks!